# bash Script to replace words

Tags: linux, bash

Looking to run a script on the server to look at a path of a file and replace a word whereas it matches in the div.

So need to replace _toself to viewers where author equals a certain email test@example.com

URL=/var/www/sever/temp/fhyw1
FILE=user.txt

```
<div class='entry'>
  <div class='pageurl'>temp/fhyw1</div>
  <div class='context'>text</div>
  <div class='subject'>testing</div>
  <div class='notetext'></div>
  <div class='signed'>USER</div>
  <div class='author'>test@example.com</div>
  <div class='color'>0</div>
  <div class='visibility'>shared</div>
  <div class='to'>_toself</div>
  <div class='num'>4</div>
</div>
<div class='entry'>
  <div class='pageurl'>temp/fhyw1</div>
  <div class='context'>text</div>
  <div class='subject'>testing</div>
  <div class='notetext'></div>
  <div class='signed'>USER</div>
  <div class='author'>user@example.com</div>
  <div class='color'>0</div>
  <div class='visibility'>shared</div>
  <div class='to'>_viewers</div>
  <div class='num'>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sed solution might work for you:

```
 sed -e '/^<div class=.entry.>/,\_^</div>_{//!{H;d};\_^</div>_!{h;d};x;/author.>test@example.com/s/_toself/SUBSTITUTE TEXT/;p;x}' text_file
```

N.B. You will need to replace `SUBSTITUE TEXT` with the `viewers`,`_viewers` or whatever

The `sed` command allows all lines other than those between `<div class=.entry.>` and `</dev>`(`.` allows for single `'`or double quotes `"`) to pass through unchanged. If the line begins with `<div class=.entry.>` it is copied to a register call the hold space (HS) and then the pattern space (PS) is deleted. All other lines are appended to the HS and then deleted accepting the line `</div>`. When this line appears the HS is swapped with the PS and if this multiline contains `author.>test@example.com` then `SUBSTITUTE TEXT` is substituted for `_toself`. The multiline is printed out regardless, then the PS replaces the HS and it in turn to printed out.

Comment: Thanks for the sed command seems to work ok but I'm getting blank lines inserted every div entry and /div ?

Comment: I must have mucked up whilst copying and pasting. Solution corrected - a regex had gone astray `\_^</div>_`

Answer (score 1):

We have some text

```
$> cat ./text 
<div class='entry'>
  <div class='pageurl'>temp/fhyw1</div>
  <div class='context'>text</div>
  <div class='subject'>testing</div>
  <div class='notetext'></div>
  <div class='signed'>USER</div>
  <div class='author'>test@example.com</div>
  <div class='color'>0</div>
  <div class='visibility'>shared</div>
  <div class='to'>_toself</div>
  <div class='num'>4</div>
</div>
<div class='entry'>
  <div class='pageurl'>temp/fhyw1</div>
  <div class='context'>text</div>
  <div class='subject'>testing</div>
  <div class='notetext'></div>
  <div class='signed'>USER</div>
  <div class='author'>user@example.com</div>
  <div class='color'>0</div>
  <div class='visibility'>shared</div>
  <div class='to'>_viewers</div>
  <div class='num'>4</div>
</div>
```

And we need to replace `_toself` 'to' value with `viewers`, but only in divs, where 'author' equals a `test@example.com`

I think sed can helps you, but you should have some experience with it to formulate all condition with sed syntax.

So, we can read file in while loop, cut it into a div-blocks and change one value by another only if blocks 'authors' value is equal some email.

```
#!/bin/bash

mail="test@example.com"
to_value_old=_toself
to_value_new=viewers

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ -z "$( echo "$line" | grep -o -P "^<\/div>$" )" ]]; then
        entry_block="${entry_block}${line}\n"
    else
        entry_block="${entry_block}</div>\n"
        entry_block="$( echo -e "${entry_block}" )"
        if [[ -n "$( echo "${entry_block}" | grep -P "\<div class=\'author\'\>${mail}\<\/div\>" )" ]]; then
            entry_block="$( echo "${entry_block}" | sed -r -e "s/<div\ class='to'>${to_value_old}<\/div>/<div\ class='to'>${to_value_new}<\/div>/"  )"
        fi
        echo "${entry_block}"
        entry_block=""
    fi
done < ./text
```

And we get

```
$> ./div.sh 
<div class='entry'>
  <div class='pageurl'>temp/fhyw1</div>
  <div class='context'>text</div>
  <div class='subject'>testing</div>
  <div class='notetext'></div>
  <div class='signed'>USER</div>
  <div class='author'>test@example.com</div>
  <div class='color'>0</div>
  <div class='visibility'>shared</div>
  <div class='to'>viewers</div>
  <div class='num'>4</div>
</div>
<div class='entry'>
  <div class='pageurl'>temp/fhyw1</div>
  <div class='context'>text</div>
  <div class='subject'>testing</div>
  <div class='notetext'></div>
  <div class='signed'>USER</div>
  <div class='author'>user@example.com</div>
  <div class='color'>0</div>
  <div class='visibility'>shared</div>
  <div class='to'>_viewers</div>
  <div class='num'>4</div>
</div>
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks for this, i'm currently getting replace_anno.sh: 19: [[: not found
replace_anno.sh: 19: [[: not found
-e </div> when trying to run it with the text file

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace all occurrences of `_toself` by something else, then `sed` will do the job perfectly.

```
sed 's/_toself/replacement_string/'
```

If you want to do this only within the div with a specified `author` then it's a bit more tricky.

Comment: Yep going to need to do it for a specified author

Comment: Not too much - Grepping and find hasn't helped too much. Looking at putting it through a while read